# When to and when not to use lambda for named scopes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking to understand the effect of lambda on this named scope:

I have two scopes defined on my model:

```
scope :credits, lambda { where("comparison_ind != 'PEER'")}

vs

scope :credits, where("comparison_ind != 'PEER'")
```

What is the difference between the two statements? comparison_ind is a column belonging to same model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### In Rails 4

**Always use lambda**. The second syntax is incorrect in Rails 4 and will throw an error (undefined method 'call' for ActiveRecord::Relation)

```
# activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb
scope = all.scoping { body.call(*args) }
```

#### In Rails 3

`scope` method behaves same way in both cases - it created a new class method called `credits`. Difference is that when given a lambda, it evaluates this lambda every time this new method is called to get the scope, while when given relation, it just uses what has been passed.

```
# activerecord/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb
options = scope_options.respond_to?(:call) ? scope_options.call(*args) : scope_options
```

In this case, lambda always return exactly same relation, so no difference will be noted.

Lambda notation is used usually to pass arguments to the scope:

```
scope :before, lambda {|date| where.created_at < date}
```

Which then can be used like:

```
Model.before(1.day.ago)
```

This is naturally impossible to write without the lambda.